# how to export symbols in NASM

Tags: gcc, assembly, nasm, x86-64

My function is not exported by NASM assembler and therefore I can not link it with my C program. I am using the `export` directive like the manual says, but it is not recognized. What is wrong? Here is how I do it:

```
[niko@dev1 test]$ cat ssefuncs.S 
use64
section .data
NEW_LINE_4_SSE  db  '1111111111111111'

section .text

export find_nl_sse

find_nl_sse:
    mov rax,NEW_LINE_4_SSE
    movntdqa xmm0,[esi]
    pcmpestri xmm0,[rax],0x0

    ret

[niko@dev1 test]$ nasm -f elf64 -o ssefuncs.o ssefuncs.S
ssefuncs.S:7: error: parser: instruction expected
[niko@dev1 test]$
```

If I omit the `export`, recompile the assembly and try to link, the resulting code won't link with my C program:

```
[niko@dev1 test]$ gcc -o bench3 ssefuncs.o bench3.o
bench3.o: In function `main':
/home/niko/quaztech/qstar/test/bench3.c:34: undefined reference to `find_nl_sse'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[niko@dev1 test]$
```

I also tried to add the `global` directive but I get the same error. Why NASM documentation is so misleading?

Comment: I heave two ideas: 1. try moving `export find_nl_sse` before `section .text` also try `global` instead of `export`. 2. in asm name it `_find_nl_sse` and in C `find_nl_sse`.

Comment: `global` and `export` do different thinigs.

Comment: @MarinovIván , it doesn't help. same error after moving export / global out of the .text section

Answer (score 9, accepted):

here is the correct way to define a label as being visible outside the current assembly unit.

```
global _main 
_main:
```

1. the `global` statement must be before the actual label
2. the label must begin with a single underscore

a C file would reference the label as

```
extern _main
```

Comment: correct, just I can't use _main, I have the "main" symbol in my C program. But it works. Thanks. "Before label" and removing "export" I think were the keys to compile successfuly

Comment: As for the underscore, when using ELF objects the leading underscore is not needed unless you explicitly override it with `-fleading-underscore`

Comment: @MichaelPetch But on a mac, you always need the underscore.

Comment: @JustinC.B.: I said ELF,not MACHO. ELF doesn't require the underscores. If you use an x86 ELF cross compiler on MacOS you don't need an underscore. If you generate MACHO objects (32 or 64-bit) then you do.' It should be pointed out the OP was using ELF.

Comment: @MichaelPetch That's reasonable, I was just pointing out that if you're using MACHO you actually need the underscore.